# Linear search arrays

Tags: c, linear-search

How do I print multiple searches from a linear search in C?

```
for (i=0; i < index; i++)
   if (array[i] == target)
          return i;
```

Is it possible to return more then one value, say, if the array has multiple elements that equals the target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning matching elements, you could print out their index values (allowing multiple values to be printed) or insert them into an array and then return that.

Comment: So i would just store the return i in a array and then use that as a index to print out ?

Comment: You could append each matching `i` value into the array, then return that.  Alternatively, you could print out each matching value of `i`.

Answer (score 2):

You could go to the trouble of allocating a dynamic array within the function but that's probably something better left to the caller to manage.

I would change the function from something like:

```
int findVal (int *array, int size, int val) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (array[i] == val)
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

to one that allowed you to specify a starting point (or, more precisely, one less than the starting point):

```
int findVal (int *array, int size, int last, int val) {
    for (int i = last + 1; i < size; i++)
        if (array[i] == val)
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

then let your client call it with:

```
int index = findVal (myarray, sizeof(myarray)/sizeof(*myarray), -1, myval);
while (index != -1) {
    // Do something with index.
    index = findVal (myarray, sizeof(myarray)/sizeof(*myarray), index, myval);
}
```

If your client wants it in an array, they can put it in an array. But, if they just want to do something ephemeral (like just print the index then forget about it), it makes little sense to waste an array for that.

Comment: +1: great answer... no effort spared :-)